# asp.net mvc customized routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add some customized routing for my MVC ASP.NET project. I've put my self-defined routes before the default one but not sure why this is not working - keep getting error 404. Any thoughts on this? I belive the first two routes can be combined as one, as recommendations? thank you!

The urls I want to access are:

- pathtoserver/dataservice/getall
- pathtoserver/dataservice/gettest/first/second
- pathtoserver/home/index - remains the default one when launching the site.

RouteConfig.cs

```
 routes.MapRoute(
             name: "DataServiceForAll",
             url: "{controller}/{action}",
             defaults: new { controller = "DataService", action = "GetAll" }
             );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DataService",
                url: "{controller}/GetTest/{first}/{second}",
                defaults: new { controller = "DataService", action = "GetTest" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
                );
```

DataServiceController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public Object GetTest(string first, string second)
{
    //do some cool thing and return the object.

}

    [HttpGet]
    public Object GetAll()
    {
//        return an json object;
    }
```

Comment: what's the url you are trying to access?

Comment: Are all URLs returning a 404?

Comment: The first one should be `url: "DataService/GetAll",` and the second one `url: "DataService/GetTest/{first}/{second}",` (but not sure if you mean `GetAll` or `GetAllJson`?). And why `public Object GetTest(..)` as opposed to `public ActionResult GetTest(..)`?

Comment: @Dainel yes, all return 404...

Comment: @Stephen Yes GetAllJson is GetAll - edited in my question. I don't need view for my controller just an json object is fine.

Comment: Then you method should be `ActionResult` or more specifically `JsonResult`. Also you first route is not really required (the default route will handle it)

Comment: is `DataServiceController` a `ApiController` ?

Comment: @Neverever, nope; it's just a normal mvc controller.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes you're right, I will change it to more specific - JsonResult. I agree with you the first one is not needed. However, my question is why I got 404...

Comment: Which one do you get the 404 on?

Comment: @Stephen he previously said all routes throw a 404. Which I don't get at all.

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling@Stephen, I know the reason now. so stupid. See the update in quesiton. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Ah, well that's silly, but I'm glad you found it, nothing like fixing your own code. Next time you post, make sure all the relevant code is there! Also please post your update as an answer so it can be marked as correct for future readers. =)

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherlingyes I will do that, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the final answer is that I forgot to name my controller class with suffix controller. If you find all your pages returning 404, make sure your class is right named and inherit from controller base class. Don't repeat my silly mistakes..:-)

Answer (score 2):

To customise your own routing in MVC, you should start with the most strict rules and end with a "catch all" rule

I would suggest the following routing config.

```
        // URL begin with "DataService/GetAll"
        /* redundant rule as suggested in comment.
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DataServiceForAll",
            url: "DataService/GetAll",
            defaults: new { controller = "DataService", action = "GetAll" }
        );
        */

        // URL begin with "DataService/GetTest"
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DataService",
            url: "DataService/GetTest/{first}/{second}",
            defaults: new { controller = "DataService", action = "GetTest" }
        );

        // Catch All 
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
```

Comment: Isn't DataServiceForAll redundant with Default in this case?

Comment: true, default route covers DataServiceForAll

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following in your web.config, it will turn processing for all extensions and as well as extensionless mode.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <!--  Web API Put Request generates an Http 405 Method Not Allowed error -->
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```